# PSU cables long enough to reach motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, cable

Is there a definite way of knowing if your power supply cables will reach the ports on a certain motherboard? I'm buying a new motherboard and power supply online and there's no way for me to really know. Plus the mobo I'm buying is a micro-atx which is a size I've never dealt with and the power connector is in a weird place: http://www.pricescan.com/Item_Images/ImagesL/267442.jpg all the way on the other side by the IDE cables.

Is there a way of being sure I can reach? The PSU I'm buying is modular but the main power connectors definitely aren't (so getting longer ones isn't an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are buying a branded power supply (although non-branded should also work)you should not worry about cable length. According to the picture power connector is not far away either. Many other boards have the power connector at similar places on the board.

See the board I have - dg41ty:

[image]